# do we need Condition.signal in ArrayBlockingQueue.put(E)

Tags: java, concurrency

I was looking at the code for `ArrayBlockingQueue.put(E)`. Do we really need the call to `notFull.signal` in the catch block? Shouldn't that signal be called by the consumer?

```
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    final E[] items = this.items;
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        try {
            while (count == items.length)
                notFull.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            notFull.signal(); // propagate to non-interrupted thread
            throw ie;
        }
        insert(e);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: I am using jdk1.6.0_23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concern seems to be that, if a condition is signaled, AND the thread is interrupted, the `await()` consumes the signal AND throws InterruptedException. However, the javadoc specifically prohibits that - if `await()` throws InterruptedException, it must not consume a signal.

The similar concern also applies to `Object.wait()`. In 1.4, the javadoc isn't very definitive. Since 1.5, the javadoc says

> Throws: InterruptedException - if another thread interrupted the current thread before or while the current thread was waiting for a notification.

which seems to imply that if `wait()` throws InterruptedException, it must not consume a notification.

Comment: I agree with your argument but not sure how the javadoc implies that. BTW, do you know why the code was simplified moving from 1.6 to 1.7?

Comment: don't know. you could post the question to http://cs.oswego.edu/mailman/listinfo/concurrency-interest

Answer (score 1):

We don't need that call at all. The newest version of the JDK (1.7.0_17) doesn't even have that catch block.

```
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    checkNotNull(e);
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (count == items.length)
            notFull.await();
        insert(e);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```